# Visual Studio C++ Compiler strange behavior, on Local variable objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, object, compiler-errors, local-variables

I'm relatively new to C++ programming and to programming per se, and I was trying to establish sort of a familiarity with expected behavior of Visual studio compiler of C++ code. ( Visual Studio 2015 )

```
class aClass {

   public:
     int a;
     int b;
}
```

Then inside a function block, when I declare an object of this class:

```
aClass obj;
cout << obj.a;
```

then I literally one time get random RAM content as the value of the variable, while other times I get the compilation error: local variable is not initialized. ( notably, whenever the compiler overcomes the error once, it never repeats it again, although it might keep repeating it multiple times before the first time it overcomes the error! )

Any advice on best practice of declaring objects,

should I rather stick with the form `aClass obj = aClass();`for consistent results.

Or any opinion of relevance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your class is missing a constructor to initialize the member variables.

Comment: Variables that have a runtime lifetime aren't initialized by default.

Comment: _while other times I get the compilation error: local variable is not initialized_ If I remember it correctly - it is a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a variable from a class or a structure then the object is constructed, but the data inside is not initialized automatically. It is up to you to initialize the data.

The values of your member variables without initialization will be *indeterminate* and using them in any way (even reading from them) is *undefined behavior*.

Depending on the class or structure, the way to initialize the data differs. If you have a constructor defined, then I recommend you use a constructor initializer list. If you have a POD-type structure (like the one you show in your code) you can simply do something like

```
aClass obj = {};  // Basically the same as `aClass obj = aClass()`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way when I explicitly declare a default constuctor within the class, then any object declared would get initialized by my default constructor, which is not true for the automatic default constructor, hence was the reason behind my question. It wasn't really a silly question at all, but rather the default constructor seems to behave differently when I provide it versus when the compiler provides it. And as usual whoever reads in rush gives back wrong answers implying response to "lack of enough awareness" of the poser of a question. Not including this answer.Thanks

Comment: @Physician A small clarification: If you define a constructor, then that alone isn't enough to initialize member variables, you need to explicitly initialize them (unless they in turn have a constructor that initializes its own members).

Comment: Yeah, I'll take it as a valuable advice, no doubt. But actually, when the class type has an explicit default constructor, then writing the statement (( type identifier; )), alone without any explicit initializer never leads to the object being considered "not initialized" by the compiler, never literally.

Answer (score 1):

> Any advice on best practice of declaring objects

Yes, how about *not* invoking undefined behavior? You're reading from uninitialized variables; sometimes the compiler detects it and sometime it does not and you see garbage coming out.

How do you deal with this? *Initialize your variables before reading from them!*